# Duplicate interface definition for class 'MyClass', looks like cached old version of MyClass

Tags: ios

I'm now stuck with this problem, xcode says duplicate interface of MyClass, but on the top bar menu, there's no path to MyClass, just MyClass.h. And this class looks like an older version of MyClass, cached or something. My latest code is just lying in the project navigator and it's different to the displaying file, if I click it, I can see the full path to MyClass on the top bar of XCode.
I tried cleaning my project and deleted derived data, but all my efforts were useless!
I'm almost desperate, can any one help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you deleted the file, and instead of selecting to delete it you just removed the reference? Go to the project folder, (not in Xcode) and search for the file, I bet you get two files.

Comment: That's correct! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Blue Gene, I solved this problem. Just search this file in finder, I found that there's a duplicate in another folder, and somehow xcode referenced that file instead of the new one. I just deleted the old file and everything goes fine.
Thank you, Blue Gene, you saved my day!